# Calculating approximate growth from three numbers

Tags: sequences-and-series, statistics, approximation

I have a set of three numbers `3600`, `5200`,`12000`; how do I calculate an approximate 4th number in the series from these figures?

Comment: You mean a sequence? I don't think set-theory tag is appropriate. Also, this problem needs more constraints and assumptions to be solved. There could be infinite possible continuation...

Comment: Hey @Memming, I have changed the tag to Sequences-and-series. Is there no way of getting an approximate 4th value from looking at the change between x1-x2 and x2-x3?

Comment: Answer is no in general. Do you have a functional form in mind?

Comment: Constraints and assumptions are crucial: after all you are trying to predict the future with literally 2 meaningless numbers.

Comment: I don't have a functional form, but I am guessing the outcome from my data (Youtube views per video :P) will be somewhere between linear and `x^2`

Comment: Is the sequence a function of time or a function of number of videos?

Comment: The function is the number of views on 3 seperate uploads, the first number being the first video

Answer (score 2):

One possible way is to look at ratios: about a factor of 1.4 from 3500 to 5200, about 2.3 from 5200 to 120000. If those two factors had both been the same, you could use them to guess the next term. Alas, they're pretty different.

One thing that might help is if we knew something about the source of the numbers. If they're the number of thousands of shares of some stock traded on Mon, Tue, Wed, then Thursday's number could be "1100" quite plausibly. If they're the number of cells in a cell colony in a agar dish, then an exponential model makes more sense.

In short: without more data, no, there's really no way to calculate an approximate fourth number in the sequence.

Comment: Thanks for the answer John, the data is how many views I'm getting on my YouTube videos, I was hoping to plot an estimated rate of growth on my channel